# Downloading the image using OkHttp gives null

Tags: android, okhttp

I tried to download image from URL using OkHttp . It returns null.

I have permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Here is my Rest Client

```
 public class RestClient {

    private static volatile RestClient instance;
    private final OkHttpClient client;

    private RestClient(Context context) throws Exception {
        client = new OkHttpClient();
    }

    public static RestClient getInstance(Context context) throws Exception {
        if (instance == null)
            synchronized (RestClient.class) {
                if (instance == null)
                    instance = new RestClient(context);
            }
        return instance;
    }

    public Call uploadPicture(Callback callback){
        String link = "http://www.101apps.co.za/images/headers/101_logo_very_small.jpg";
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(String.format(link))
                .get()
                .build();
        Call call = client.newCall(request);
        call.enqueue(callback);
        return call;
    }
}
```

Here is my getPicture method in the main activity

```
   public void getPicByURL() {

        try {
            RestClient.getInstance(getActivity()).uploadPicture(new Callback() {

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {

                    final String json = response.body().string();
                    if (response.code() == Constants.SUCCESSFUL_DOWNLOAD) {
                        ResponseBody in = response.body();
                        InputStream inputStream = in.byteStream();
                        BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
                                                updateImage(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bufferedInputStream));
                    } 
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private void updateImage(final Bitmap bitmap) {

        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (bitmap != null) {
                    mSelectedPic.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.show_error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
  }
```

`updateImage()` method takes bitmap = null. I don`t know what I doing wrong. Please help.

Comment: Did you check the url? opening your url in borwser gives me 404 not found

Comment: @Raghunandan - yes. Another URL returns null too

Comment: With that image url (`http://www.101apps.co.za/images/headers/101_logo_very_small.jpg`) why don't you use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) or [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)?

Answer (score 3):

Hi its work for me try this

```
  OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
  Request request = new Request.Builder().url("https://www.101apps.co.za/images/headers/101_logo_very_small.jpg").get().build();

            client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                    Log.i("Tag","error"+e.getMessage());
                }

               @Override
                public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {

                   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                   ImageView imageView (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.down_imageView);

                            ResponseBody in = response.body();
                            InputStream inputStream = in.byteStream();
                            Log.i("inputStream","inputstream value = "+inputStream);
                            // convert inputstram to bufferinoutstream
                            BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
                            Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bufferedInputStream);
                            Log.i("bitmap","bitmap value = "+bitmap);
                            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                           }
                    });

               }
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

With your current Url (`http://www.101apps.co.za/images/headers/101_logo_very_small.jpg`) and your purpose (loading the image into ImageView only), I suggest you use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) or [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) instead.

Sample code if using Picasso:

```
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        Picasso.with(this)
                .load("http://www.101apps.co.za/images/headers/101_logo_very_small.jpg")
                .into(imageView);
```

Hope it helps!